# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused After server changed

Tags: php, pdo

I have made a login php script and it was working great, but now I changed my server I'm trying to connect but I got this error message : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

My function to connect is this:

```
public function connect()
  {
      try
      {
        $cont = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $username,$password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
      }
      catch(PDOException $e)
      {
        die($e->getMessage());
      }

    return $cont;
  }
```

I have tried also to put a port inside the new PDO but nothing changed.

I'm not so familiar with these so maybe it's a noobie mistake.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're 100% sure the port is correct have you tried using the server's IP address instead of the hostname? Also, exactly how did you try adding the port number to your connection?

Comment: Did you check your `$server` and `$db` variables ? Does the database exists on the new server ?

Comment: Error 2002 usually indicates that it failed to connect to MySQL on *localhost*. I would guess you used to run MySQL on the same host where you run your PHP code, but now they're on different hosts, but your `$server` variable is still set to 'localhost'. Now it's trying to connect to a local MySQL instance, but there is none running on localhost. You need to set `$server` to the hostname or IP address of the host where your MySQL service is running.

Comment: @BillKarwinI really don't know what was happening before but now with the ip is running perfectly...Thanx anyway!